# Are there any practical advantages of LSTMs over transformers?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, transformer

There are a number of [articles noting that transformers have significant advantages](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/why-are-lstms-struggling-to-matchup-with-transformers-a1cc5b2557e3) over "traditional" RNNs like LSTMs. And the industry as a whole have been moving away from LSTMs. My question is, in the domain of NLP, do LSTMs (or GRUs) have any practical benefits/advantages over transformers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LSTMs/GRUs have lower computational and memory requirements than transformers.

Depending on the case, using an LSTM instead of a Transformer may make sense due to those factors. For instance, using Transformers on mobile devices or embedded devices with CPU and memory limitations is not easy.

Also, in machine translation, having a Transformer encoder and an LSTM decoder may not significantly impact the resulting translation quality.